# How to extract a text from java script using PHP dom or regex

Tags: php, regex, dom

I want extrat node value from following java script part.The java script is contained in html head section.I want to do it with PHP html dom or regex.

```
<script>  
     *****************************************
     ********************************** 
     document.loginform.action ="../Login1.action";
 document.loginform.submit();
 }
    </script>
```

I want get the text between the   document.loginform.action ="I want to get this text"; the two quotes. 
please help me.

Comment: This question was not related to Java, but to Javascript. About your question, you have multiple solutions. If you're sure your HTMl is correctly formated then you can parse it with any XML parser, retrieving the `//head/script` node with XPath, then with a regular expression get what you want. Or use something like this: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php  then look for `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` to retrieve the node you want.

Comment: "/Login1.action" this will always change.Please give me a ready to use script.

Comment: Yeah, sure: http://goo.gl/Wh1CO

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:
Get the `<script>` node from the HTML like this:

```
x=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
str = x[0].innerHTML;
```

This will get you the entire script content between your `<scrip> and </script>` nodes.
 Split the `str`'

```
var arr = str.split(":");
```

This will get you an array with  all the lines.Now group all `document.loginform` strings in the array and proceed further.You need to check a string that contains an 'action' preferably.That will help you to get more accurate results.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i want to get only "Login1.action" ,please give the code if possible. Because i am not familiar with it.I want it for my project.

Answer (score 1):

To do exactly whay you've asked, you can use a regular expression and the text property of each script element, however I don't think you'll find it very robust or practical.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var script, scripts = document.scripts;
  var re = /document\.loginform\.action =/;
  var text;

  for (var i=0, iLen=scripts.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    script = scripts[i];

    if (re.test(script.text)) {
      text = script.text.match(/document\.loginform\.action ="[^"]+/)[0];
      alert(text.split('"')[1]);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the result in string.

Comment: Not want Java script.I want a php script.

Comment: People is not here to create your scripts. Try something at least, and then if you have problems, come here to ask. This is not a good way to ask for an answer.

Comment: am sorry.It was a little urgent so i asked.

Answer (score -1):

You are not searching even for a second or using what people suggest you, this is a bad way to ask for people help.
This is a solution using regex.

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOD
....
<script>  
     *****************************************
     ********************************** 
     document.loginform.action ="../Login1.action";
 document.loginform.submit();
 }
    </script>
.....
EOD;
$match = preg_match('/document\.loginform\.action\s*=\s*"([^"]+)";/isU', $html, $result);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

You may want to achieve the same using a DOM Parser, you will need to check here: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php for more informations.

Comment: You should read the FAQ of this website ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask ) in order to understand how it works here, or you won't often have an answer to your questions. People probably won't want to help you next time you are needing something.